# AWS Lambda function handler threw an uncaught exception: No serializer found for class

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

**Background:**

We have a AWS CloudFormation stack which we use to deploy several resources including the Lambda function. The CloudFormation also deploys StackSets which in turn creates resources in multiple other regions.

**Problem:**

While deploying the CloudFormation stack we are receiving below error:

**Error:**

> Lambda function handler threw an uncaught exception: No serializer found for class software.amazon.events.eventbus.ResourceModel$ResourceModelBuilder and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: software.amazon.cloudformation.proxy.ProgressEvent["callbackContext"]->software.amazon.events.eventbus.CallbackContext["resourceModelBuilder"])

We are unable to resolve this issue even after several attempts the stack is failing and getting rollbacked. Also we have not made any changes to the Lambda function which might cause this issue. Request to help.

**Note**: We have confirmed that the issue is not related with Template errors or code issue

Comment: Can you show the template?

Comment: I might not be able to share the template, but I can confirm that this is not a Template or code issue. The error appears to be internal AWS error.